# why nslookup kent.edu and www.kent.edu output different result?

Tags: networking

nslookup  kent.edu
*** Can't find server name for address 221.176.88.95: Non-existent domain

*** Can't find server name for address 211.138.164.6: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  221.176.88.95

Name:    kent.edu

nslookup  www.kent.edu
*** Can't find server name for address 221.176.88.95: Non-existent domain

*** Can't find server name for address 211.138.164.6: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  221.176.88.95

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www-new.kent.edu
Address:  131.123.246.53
Aliases:  www.kent.edu

why nslookup kent.edu and www.kent.edu output different result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be occurring because there is no "A" record set up for kent.edu but there is one set up for www.kent.edu.  The chain of logic I used (under Linux) to determine this:

dig kent.edu ns

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> kent.edu ns ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got
>   answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55191 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;kent.edu.           IN  NS
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: kent.edu.      223 IN  NS  dhcp.net.kent.edu.
>   kent.edu.     223 IN  NS  ns.net.kent.edu.
>   kent.edu.     223 IN  NS  adns03.net.kent.edu.
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns.net.kent.edu.   231 IN  A   131.123.1.1
>   dhcp.net.kent.edu.    231 IN  A   131.123.252.2
>   adns03.net.kent.edu.  231 IN  A   128.146.94.250
>
> ;; Query time: 1 msec ;; SERVER: 10.0.3.254#53(10.0.3.254) ;; WHEN:
>   Wed Jan  1 17:00:57 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135

dig @131.123.1.1 kent.edu a

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @131.123.1.1 kent.edu a ; (1 server found) ;;
>   global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY,
>   status: NOERROR, id: 22704 ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0,
>   AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0 ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not
>   available
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;kent.edu.           IN  A
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: kent.edu.       300 IN  SOA ns.net.kent.edu.
>   postmaster.net.kent.edu. 23142476 1200 180 2419200 300
>
> ;; Query time: 265 msec ;; SERVER: 131.123.1.1#53(131.123.1.1) ;;
>   WHEN: Wed Jan  1 17:01:56 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80

dig @131.123.1.1 www.kent.edu a

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @131.123.1.1 www.kent.edu a ; (1 server found) ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9928 ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3 ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.kent.edu.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION: www.kent.edu.        300 IN  CNAME   www-new.kent.edu. www-new.kent.edu. 300 IN  A   131.123.246.53

;; AUTHORITY SECTION: kent.edu.     300 IN  NS  adns03.net.kent.edu. kent.edu.      300 IN  NS  ns.net.kent.edu. kent.edu.      300 IN  NS  dhcp.net.kent.edu.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns.net.kent.edu. 300 IN  A   131.123.1.1 dhcp.net.kent.edu.  300 IN  A   131.123.252.2 adns03.net.kent.edu.  300 IN  A   128.146.94.250

;; Query time: 274 msec ;; SERVER: 131.123.1.1#53(131.123.1.1) ;; WHEN: Wed Jan  1 17:02:20 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 177
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, more fundamentally and unstated in davidgo's answer:  Because `kent.edu` and `www.kent.edu` are two *different* domain names.  Different domain names, that whoever administers them has assigned different DNS resource records to.  A human being has decided that what you saw is what the DNS data are going to be (almost certainly because it's not permitted to have an alias at a delegation point) for those two different domain names.  It's that simple.